# Matplotlib and FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using anaconda3 and facing such problem:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory 'C:\Users\pobox\.matplotlib\fontlist-v300.json'

And the fact is in the folder .matplotlib I didn't find  such file fontlist-v300.json.

I know the problem may be connected with the matplotlib, but the problem is occuring even after updating the version of matplotlib.

Any ideas how to fix it?

[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9rmI.png)

Comment: I'm following the project: https://github.com/naokishibuya/car-behavioral-cloning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from the update of the issue https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12173/, you could try update matplotlib to the latest version. But people still reporting the problems persists, so the bug might still in works.

You could try this option, and match it with your current Python environments

For the file itself, you may try to check this: https://gitlab.lagash.com/josemg/sofy-luis-quality/blob/b1ddf1ec3577bdec0d798c8586c30b6d6fc10f5f/.cache/matplotlib/fontlist-v300.json

Comment: Well, I'm using the version: matplotlib 3.2.2, and I was hoping they dealt with the bug

Comment: You can try the link I added to reproduce the file, but I don't know if it works.